# Unwanted member change because of reference

Tags: c#, parameter-passing

I am writing a piece of code but cannot figure out why it is showing some (from my point of view) weird behaviour. I get this is due to how I have written the code, but I cannot understand why it is not doing what I want it to do.

I have an eventhandler:

```
private void heatFinishedHandler(object sender, List<Kart> e)
    {
        mainForm.enableControls();
        server.karts = e;
    }
```

If I add `e.Clear();` to it, it also clears `server.karts`.

The argument `e` comes from another class:

```
private List<Kart> kartlist = new List<Kart>();

heatFinished?.Invoke(this, kartlist);
```

The `heatFinished` event and the `heatFinishedEventHandler` are connected.

What do I need to do to get `e` by value, instead of reference? Or is it a value type, but is it pointing to `kartlist`?

I want to be able to get the value of `e` and store it in `server.karts`, not being able to change `kartlist`.

Comment: `server.karts = e.ToList()` ? Do note, `ToList()` doesn't copy the Karts, only creates a copy to the list. Which may lead to other side effects if you are not careful

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make a copy of the list you pass to the function like

```
private List<Kart> kartlist = new List<Kart>();

heatFinished?.Invoke(this, kartlist.ToList());
```

Or do it inside the function like

```
private void heatFinishedHandler(object sender, List<Kart> e)
{
    mainForm.enableControls();
    server.karts = e.ToList();
}
```

`.ToList()` will make a new List-instance with the same values as the original one.

Comment: Thank you! This works! I don't get why e isn't passed by value (where the value contains only the list, and not a pointer to the list).